# Taking union of two lists based on column

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I am taking a union of two lists using Linq to Sql. Using List1 and List2:

```
 var tr = List1.Union(List2).ToList();
```

Union works fine, but the problem is it is checking each column and removes some of the rows that I want. So I was wondering if there is a a way I can perform a union based on one column only, like let's say `id`, of each list?

Something Like:

```
var t = List1.id.Union(List2.id).ToList();
```

This doesn't work, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this, either with LINQ or T-SQL

Comment: that doesn't make much sense, if I'm not wrong. If rows are "merged", that's because all of their values are identical (Id included). So compare just id will potentially remove more rows, not less...

Comment: I want to take Union of two lists based on the i.e date column only. So if dubplicate date rows exists it only takes the one.

Answer (score 5):

You should use this [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336942.aspx)() overload (with a custom equality comparer) , or something like this:

```
list1.Concat(list2).GroupBy(x => x.DateProperty).Select(m => m.First());
```

The first solution is certainly more efficient.

Comment: The `GroupBy` solution isn't actually all that inefficient.  It's effectively using the same general algorithm as `Union` is (both it and `GroupBy` are using a `HashSet` for the values).  Yours has a bit of extra overhead with all of the iterators, but it's not much.

Comment: @Servy I'll keep this, thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you need a custom `IEqualityComparer` with `Union`. I have one that's really dynamic, big block of code incoming though:

```
public class PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty> 
    : IEqualityComparer<TObject>
{
    Func<TObject, TProperty> _selector;
    IEqualityComparer<TProperty> _internalComparer;
    public PropertyEqualityComparer(Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> innerEqualityComparer = null)
    {
        _selector = propertySelector;
        _internalComparer = innerEqualityComparer;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(TObject obj)
    {
        return _selector(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
    public bool Equals(TObject x, TObject y)
    {
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> comparer = 
            _internalComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TProperty>.Default;
        return comparer.Equals(_selector(x), _selector(y));
    }
}
public static class PropertyEqualityComparer
{
    public static PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
        GetNew<TObject, TProperty>(Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelector)
    { 
        return new PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
            (propertySelector);
    }
    public static PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
        GetNew<TObject, TProperty>
        (Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelector, 
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> comparer)
    { 
        return new PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
            (propertySelector, comparer);
    }
}
```

Now, all you need to do is call Union with that equality comparer (instantiated with a lambda that fits your circumstance):

```
var tr = List1.Union(List2, PropertyEqualityComparer.GetNew(n => n.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that in the example you gave you're calling the selector on each object quite a few times.  If the projection is cheap that's not so bad, but if it's expensive, or worse, if it causes side effects (as bad of an idea as that is) this class will cause problems.  If you use a `DistinctBy` implementation, such as that in MoreLINQ, you can ensure that the selector is called exactly once per item in the list.

Comment: `DistinctBy` is better, true. However, just wondering why it would get called more than once? It's using a hashset and the method seems like it only goes over each object once. Also it was meant for another question, but I found it quite useful, so it's my go to "use when you do not want to make extra long equality comparer for twenty different properties" option.

Comment: Well, it will call the selector once per item for `GetHashCode`.  Then, for every time `Equals` is called it's performing the selector an additional time.  So technically if there are never any conflicting hashes you'll never call the projection more than once, but that's unlikely to be the case.  As I said, it's okay to use it when the projection is cheap and side-effect-free.  It's important that anyone using it understands that drawback though, hence my comment.

Comment: @Servy I get it now. Still, DistinctBy is better, but this should be fine unless the collection is massive. Thanks for that though, I overlooked it.

Comment: The size of the collection isn't particularly important; it's a matter of what's being done in the projection.  If the projection is, for example, executing an DB query to go get a value, even a very small collection would have problems if it's called more often than needed.

Comment: @Servy That's quite true, too.

Comment: @Servy DistinctBy (and morelinq in general) is limited to linq2objects, no ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Correct, as is this answer, and any answer involving an `IEqualityComparer` as that entire concept is specific to linq to objects.

Comment: @Servy I thought so, but why is there an extension method Union overload with an IEqualityComparer on Queryable ?

Answer (score 0):

try somthing this

```
var List3 = List1.Join(
List2, 
l1 => l1.Id,
l2 => l2.Id,
(l1, l2) => new Model
{
   Id = l1.Id,
   Val1 = l1.Val1 or other,
   Val2 = l2.Val2  or other
});
```

for more details you can show your model

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var merged = new List<Person>(list1);
merged.AddRange(list2.Where(p2 => 
                list1.All(p1 => p1.Id != p2.Id)));
```